# Extendscript Comp creation

Tags: javascript, automation, adobe, extendscript, after-effects

I have a quick question and I've seem to hit a deadend here. I'm trying to cycle through a selected folder and import all the assets from said folder, create a comp out of one specific asset and then layer the rest of the assets ontop of that specific comp. It all seems to work until it tries to layer the rest of the assets. Is there something I'm missing here?

Thanks so much!

```
 //Source Folder
//Manually select folder
var sourceFolder = Folder.selectDialog("Select folder with source files");


// Array holding source footage and directories
var sourceList = new Array();
var sourceList2 = new Array();
var sFolder = new Array();


//calls functions
importPlate(sourceFolder, sourceList, sourceList2);
genComp(sourceList);
//imports plate into project

function importPlate(sourceFolder, sourceList, sourceList2)
{
    var sourceFiles = sourceFolder.getFiles();
    $.writeln(sourceFolder);
    var footage;
    var footage2;
    var str = "";
    var word = new Array();
    var plate = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < sourceFiles.length; i++) 
    {
        str = sourceFiles[i].toString();
        word = str.split(".");
        plate = word[1];
        if(plate == "mov")
        {
            $.writeln(typeof footage)
            $.writeln(sourceList);
            $.writeln(typeof sourceList);
            $.write("This ran once");
            footage = app.project.importFile(new ImportOptions(sourceFiles[i]));
            sourceList.push(footage);            
        }
        else
        {
            sourceList2.push(footage2);
            footage2 = app.project.importFile(new ImportOptions(sourceFiles[i]));            
        }
    }

}


// Generate Compositions
function genComp(footage, footage2)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < sourceList.length; i++) 
    {
        var sourceFootage = sourceList[i];
        $.writeln(sourceFootage);
        var compName = sourceFootage.name.substring(0, sourceFootage.name.indexOf(".")) + "_" + i;
        $.writeln(compName);
        var newComp = app.project.items.addComp(compName, 4096, 2160, 1, sourceFootage.duration, sourceFootage.frameRate);
        $.writeln(newComp);
        newComp.layers.add(sourceFootage);
        for (var i = 0; i < sourceList2.length; i++)
        {
            $.writeln(sourceList[i]);
            var sourceFootage2 = sourceList2[i];
            $.writeln(sourceFootage2);
            newComp.layers.add ();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Should the last line be  `newComp.layers.add (sourceFootage2 );`?

Comment: @stib ah whoops yeah it should be. Still gives me the same error there though.

Answer (score 0):

In your importPlate function, the else statement to help populate your variable for `footage2` pushes the empty variable to `sourceList2` before defining what it is. This is likely what's causing your 'undefined' when adding `sourceFootage2` into your `newComp.layers.add()` at the bottom of the `genComp` function.

E.G.

```
         else
        {
            sourceList2.push(footage2);
            footage2 = app.project.importFile(new ImportOptions(sourceFiles[i]));            
        }
```

Should be:

```
        else
        {
            footage2 = app.project.importFile(new ImportOptions(sourceFiles[i])); 
            sourceList2.push(footage2);              
        }
```

I tested this and it seems to do what you had intended! Cheers!